# Ubuntu 14.04 not publishing printers on network

Tags: 14.04, printing

I have two ubuntu machines. One has a usb connected printer and works fine from the computer it is connected. I set up a remote printer on the second machine with a url of ipp://10.0.1.201/printers/remote_name_of_printer. Every time I attempt to print to it, I get "The printer is not responding". I also tried using url of ipp://10.0.1.201:631/printers/remote_name_of_printer and get the same.

Answer (score 0):

On the system with the printer, open `http://localhost:631/admin` and check ✔ "`Share printers connected to this system`" and "`Allow printing from the internet`". Think about checking the other two "`Allow ...`" boxes. Remember to click on "`Change Settings`"

Comment: Both are selected and I have clicked on Change Setting. I do not see any printers on this box from other linux or osx. All work locally fine.

Comment: Inspect `/var/log/cups/*_log`, Restart CUPS with `sudo service cups restart` and re-inspect `/var/log/cups/*_log`. Check firewall statuses and rules on all involved systems. Run `wireshark` and see if packets arrive at `10.0.1.201:631`.